# How to solve systems with TI-nspire automatically

Tags: variables, system, equation, ti-nspire

is there any solution to solve a large system of equations in a program with the TI-nspire without typing all the variable names by hand?

For example, the function solve([1  2; 3  4]* [x; y] = 2,{x,y}) requires typing x,y manually. How is this done if the dimensions of the matrix can change?

I tried to use the function constructMat(x[i], i, j, 5, 1) which partly works but solve doesn't accept this function as variable as second argument.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while ago, i couldnt find any solution but to manually type the list of variables. Ive found the way to construct the list of unkowns (B_n):
`i:=3:j:=4:B_n:=newlist(j+1) For i1,i,i+j:B_n[i1-i+1]:=expr("b"&string(i1)):endfor`

with result: {b3,b4,b5,b6,b7}.
I dont remember exactly why this didnt work, i guess its the same reason (solve or zeros function will not accept this list as an argument)